# Fourier Series trouble

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series

"For $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ with period $2$, determine the Fourier series.

Show that $\pi^2 / 6 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^2)$".

How is the first part of this exercise related to the last?

EDIT: Found the solution. Simply do the initial part of the problem and then the latter part of the exercise follows easily.

Comment: Don't worry. You'll find that out once you have the Fourier series.

Comment: I am posting my answer as a comment rather than as an answer. The relation you mention is quite famous and there are many ways to show the correctness of this series. One of them is through Fourier Series but that is more rigorous and not easy (at least not for me). Here is a link to several proofs of this famous  problem, Fourier approach is one of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant Fourier series is
$$
x^2= {1\over 3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4(-1)^n\over n^2\pi^2}\cos(n\pi x), \quad -1<x<1.
$$
Evaluating at $x=1$
$$
1^2={1\over 3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4\over n^2\pi^2},
$$
and a little rearranging:
$$
{\pi^2\over 6}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^2}.
$$

Comment: Yep. Exactly how I found it earlier.